# How to get key value from a nested hash with escape characters

Tags: json, ruby, hash, hashmap

I'm trying to get some key/values from a hash but haven't figured out the best way to do it. Also, I then need to put the results in a table with the keys as column headers.

I tried `map`, `select` and `dig` but I just get various errors.

```
require 'json'

json_hash = {:results=>["{\"resourceId\":\"i-5ee33\",\"configuration\":{\"instanceType\":\"m4.2xlarge\"},\"tags\":[{\"tag\":\"aws:au\\u003db\",\"value\":\"b-1a\",\"key\":\"awsss\"},{\"tag\":\"Kernluster\\ulues\",\"value\":\"blu\",\"key\":\"Kster\"},{\"tag\":\"Kuole\\udter\",\"value\":\"master\",\"key\":\"Kule\"},{\"tag\":\"Name\\uwest-1a\",\"value\":\"st-1a\",\"key\":\"Name\"}]}"], :query_info=>{:select_fields=>[{:name=>"[FILTERED]"}, {:name=>"[FILTERED]"}, {:name=>"[FILTERED]"}]}, :next_token=>"YwutZrD0Ow9Qh3HoYbiC"}

keys_to_extract = ['resourceId', 'instanceType', 'tags']
x = json_hash.map do |w|
  w.select { |k,_| keys_to_extract.include? k }
end

puts x
```

No error results shown.

Comment: Welcome to SO! The "hash" contains a JSON encoded string, so the first thing to do is decode those into a Ruby hash of arrays. `JSON[string]` will do that for the JSON strings. It's always important to understand the data coming into your code. Please make sure your code and associated data is usable otherwise we spin our wheels trying to help you. Please read "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the contents are still in a JSON string. You need to parse them in order for Ruby to access them:

```
json_hash[:results].map! { |str| JSON.parse(str) }
```

Though I hope you have a typo there because the JSON is invalid. A `\u` is supposed to be followed by 4 hexadecimal digits, but you have

```
{"tag":"Name\uwest-1a","value":"st-1a","key":"Name"}
```

which is gibberish.

Comment: perhaps add comment that `.map!` modifies the `json_hash`

Comment: This operation is not idempotent, one should prefer `map` chained to handlers.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin true, if you want to carefully preserve your garbage data, you should use `map` instead